# Apache Solr with Php

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to setup apache solr search for one of my project. I have installed solr 3.6 in my development server and it is reachable with

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/admin/
```

I tried to put the sample application available in php manual but it is setting username and password for solr. I am not sure where can I get this information from. I have also tried below code from net but I was getting 500 error whenever I run it

```
$options = array (
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
);

//$client = new SolrClient($options, "4.0"); // use 4.0 for any version of Solr 4.x, ignore this parameter for previous versions

$doc = new SolrInputDocument();

$doc->addField('id', 100);
$doc->addField('title', 'Hello Wolrd');
$doc->addField('description', 'Example Document');
$doc->addField('cat', 'Foo');
$doc->addField('cat', 'Bar');

$response = $client->addDocument($doc);

$client->commit();

/* ------------------------------- */

$query = new SolrQuery();

$query->setQuery('hello');

$query->addField('id')
->addField('title')
->addField('description')
->addField('cat');

$queryResponse = $client->query($query);

$response = $queryResponse->getResponse();

print_r( $response->response->docs );
```

Please help

Comment: Can you provide the output of `$response->response->docs`

Comment: @crmpicco when I run this, I am getting a 500 internal server error. $doc = new SolrInputDocument().. solr instance creation itself is giving this error and not able to proceed from there

Comment: what does the 500 in the error log mention ? do you have the error trace ?

Comment: So PHP throwing a 500 error? Please locate the `error.log` of apache-php and post relevant here. If its tomcat that throws the error, post the relevant entry from `catalina.out`

Comment: I had checked the log and it shows class not found error

Answer (score 1):

your solr version is 3.6 so you should assign $client = new SolrClient($options);

```
$client = new SolrClient($options, "4.0"); // I see that in your code you commented this line which is required thinking that it is only for solt 4.x in your case, you should uncomment it and only remove the "4.0" in order to create a client.
```

To create a client :

```
$options = array (
    'host' => "localhost",
    'port' => 8983, //port is required
    'path' => '/solr/collection1', //collection1 or core are mandatory it can be just /solr/
);
$client = new SolrClient($options); //for solr 3.x
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the example code, you are not setting the port in your `$options` array. Should be:

```
  var $options = array(
       'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
       'port' => '8080',
  );
```

That could be the cause of the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 3 things host, port, and webapp. I hope you have included the service.php file in that.

```
var $options = array(
   'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
   'port' => '8080', //Port number where solr runs.
   'webapp' => '/solr/',  //path of the webapp.
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Master site configuration**

For settings.php file in your master site you do not have to change much. Leave your $databases array as it as. Master site will store all the user names, passwords, and sessions.
For settings.php file in your master site you do not have to change much. Leave your $databases array as it as. Master site will store all the user names, passwords, and sessions.

```
$databases = array(
    'default' =>
    array(
        'default' =>
        array(
            'database' => 'drupal1',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Slave sites configuration**

The slave sites shall be connected to the Master site's database for certain tables, specially the ones that include user information. For settings.php file in your slave sites you need to specify master site database and call its users and other tables. We can do so by adding configuration settings within the "prefix" key of the $databases array.

```
$databases = array(
    'default' =>
    array(
        'default' =>
        array(
            'database' => 'drupal2',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => array(
                'default' => 'drupal2.',
                'users' => 'drupal1.',
                'sessions' => 'drupal1.',
                'role' => 'drupal1.',
                'authmap' => 'drupal1.',
                'users_roles' => 'drupal1.',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

For more detailed instruction visit - [How to set up and use Apache Solr in php](http://drupixels.com/blog/how-set-and-use-apache-solr-php)